# Can an Indian travel to the Caribbean, avoiding USA, with the help of a transit visa?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, transit-visas, caribbean

I want to travel to the Caribbean.

What is the fastest route there from India, without having a US visa?

Transit visas is more likely.

Comment: Where in the Carribean? There is a lot of countries there.

Comment: From where in India? And what do you mean by transit visa more likely, are you willing to get a transit visa, in which case you can fly any airline passing through USA?

Comment: You can fly from Mumbai to Havana, Cuba with a connection in Europe.

Comment: BOM-CDG-SXM. Needs a type A airport transit visa for CDG though. Enjoy your holiday!

Comment: @pnuts or via Europe.  Many European possessions in the Caribbean, and former European possessions, have direct flights from their associated European countries.